# Error al dividir dos columnas

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

```
      df:   POS       BP         Proportion       total
           042(T)     T             4               6
           062(T)     C             2               6
           072(T)     G             1               6
           082(T)     A             6               6
           092(T)     T             6               6
```

Ejecuto el siguiente código para obtener la frecuencia de cada valor: 
          df$Freq <- round(((df$Propotion*100)/df$total),2)

y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
    Error in (df$Propotion * 100)/df$total : non-numeric argument to binary operator In addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(df$Propotion, 100) :‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Te fijaste si `Proportion` y `Total` son numéricas? Por el tipo de error quizás sean caractereres, aunque se "vean" como números. Prueba `sapply(df, class)` y tendrás un vector con las clases de todas las columnas de `df`. Si esas dos no dicen `numeric` prueba coercionarlas con `as.numeric()` primero.

Comment: Coincido con @mpaladino, `df$Propotion` seguramente es un `factor`, el texto final del error dice: `‘*’ not meaningful for factors`. La sugerencia es convertirlo a numérico, aunque lo ideal es revisar la importación de estos datos y hacer que esta columna sea tratada como numérica desde el inicio.

Comment: Sí,  seguramente son de la clase `factor` En ese caso `as.numeric(as.character(df$Proportion))`. La coerción directa de un factor a numérico  regresa el entero asociado a la etiqueta, por eso hay que forzarlo a `character` primero. En este caso no creo que sea problema de importación, por otra pregunta de @Adrian P.L. creo que esos "factores" son el resultado de separar una columna en varias extrayendo el número.

Comment: En efecto, eran factores usando sapply(df, class) he logrado ver que no tenía caracter numérico mis variables. Por lo que las he convertido a caracter numérico y ya si me deja hacer la proporción. Muchas gracias a los dos. Si, era el resultado de separar una columna en varias.